# from View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

[image]

I'm new to ASP.NET Core MVC and coding in general.

This is imitation of practicing craps pay out for the casino dealers.

- Bet: 30 on the picture is how much money on the WORLD BET.
- Dice Roll: 3. Depends on what rolls the calculation will be different.

The user need to submit the correct answer (66 in this scenario).

What needs to be done is to have a little settings window where you can apply configuration for the practice. Let's say I want min bet: 5 and max bet: 100 . And I will have questions in this range. OR I want the min bet: 25 and max bet: 500 and  increment of 25. ( So I will have bet question is only 25,50,75,100,125 etc... till 500)

I want to have a little settings window where I can apply configuration.

This is my `WorldController`:

```
public class WorldController : Controller
{
    private const EGames currentGame = EGames.WorldBet;

    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public WorldController(UserManager<User> userManager, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Play(int? min, int? max, int? increment)
    {
        PropBet worldBet = GenerateWorlBet(min, max, increment);
        return View(worldBet);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Play(PropBet propBet)
    {
        User? user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

        PlayerGames? worldBetGame = await _context.PlayerGames.FirstOrDefaultAsync(g => g.UserId == user!.Id && g.GameType == currentGame);

        if (worldBetGame is null)
        {
            worldBetGame = new PlayerGames { GameType = currentGame, UserId = user!.Id, TempBestResult = 0, LongestCorrectAsnwerStreak = 0, TotalAnswers = 0 };

            await _context.PlayerGames.AddAsync(worldBetGame);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        if (propBet.Answer == CalculateCorrectAnswer(propBet.Bet, propBet.RolledNumber))
        {
            worldBetGame.TempBestResult++;
            worldBetGame.TotalAnswers++;

            if (worldBetGame.TempBestResult > worldBetGame.LongestCorrectAsnwerStreak)
            {
                worldBetGame.LongestCorrectAsnwerStreak = worldBetGame.TempBestResult;
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Play));
        }
        else
        {
            propBet.ErrorMessage = "Wrong Payout!";
            worldBetGame.TempBestResult = 0;
            worldBetGame.TotalAnswers++;

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return View(propBet);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my view for play:

```
@model PropBet
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Play";
}

<div class="container">
    
    <hr />
    <div>

        <h2>World Bet</h2>

        @if (Model.ErrorMessage != null)
        {
            <p>@Model.ErrorMessage</p>
        }

        <p>Bet: @Model.Bet</p>
        <p>Dice Roll: @Model.RolledNumber</p>
        <div class="row">
            <form asp-action="Play">
                <input asp-for="@Model.Bet" name="bet" hidden />
                <input asp-for="@Model.RolledNumber" name="rolledNumber" hidden />

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="min">Min Bet</label>
                    <input type="number" id="min" name="min" min="5" max="5000" step="5" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="min">Max Bet</label>
                    <input type="number" id="max" name="max" min="5" max="5000" step="5" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="min">Increment</label>
                    <select id="increment" name="increment">
                        <option value="5" selected>5</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="@Model.Answer">Answer:</label>
                    <input asp-for="@Model.Answer" type="number" min="0" required autofocus />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Answer</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to pass those settings parameters to the `GenerateWorlBet(min, max, increment);` from the view.

First I thought I can add settings in the form and pass them to the controller. Then I realized that when we submit, we go to `[HttpPost]` `Play` method, and after evaluation if answer is correct it will redirect us to the `[HttpGet] Play` and I will not have those parameters.

Then I thought maybe to add them in the controller

```
private const EGames currentGame = EGames.WorldBet;

private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

int Min;
int Max;
int Increment;
```

Then when we make submit it goes here:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Play(PropBet propBet int? min, int? max, int? increment)
{
    // and we do manipulation 
    Min = min;
    Max = max;
    Increment = increment;

    // logic
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Play));
}
```

After that we do this manipulation

```
public IActionResult Play()
{
    PropBet worldBet = GenerateWorlBet(Min, Max, Increment);
    return View(worldBet);
}
```

The third option was to do some kind of `ViewData` or `ViewBag`. I have never done this.

I am not sure what is the best approach to this... Or maybe there is another simple solution... Thank you for your feedback...

Comment: Hi @Console.WL, I think use TempData would be better for your scenario.

Comment: [Session state management in ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-8.0).